How can I wait for the downloads to be completed in Puppeteer?
I have a form that after pressing the submit button starts downloading a file.
I need to wait until that download has been completed, then move on to the next step.
How can I do this?
//get all years from the select
const years = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name=year] option')).map(element=> element.value)
);

//iterate through all years and download the files
for (const year of years) {
    //wait for the export button and the year select to be available
    await page.waitForSelector('input[value=Export]');
    await page.waitForSelector('select[name=year]');

    //set the download path for the files
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: `./apia-parcels/${organization}/${year}`});

    //select the year and click the export button
    await page.select('select[name=year]', year);
    await page.click('input[value=Export]');

    !!!!!! Here I need to wait until the download is completed before redirect!!!!!

    //if the period does not have any data, the select will be replaced with a message with 2 buttons.
    //if the message is displayed, just refresh the page and continue with the next year
    await page.goto('https://lpis.apia.org.ro/export_shape/index.php');
}

Puppeteer: v22.8.0 Node: v22.1.0

Put await page,goto(..... outside the loop ?

https://lpis.apia.org.ro/export_shape/index.php doesn't load for me, and I'm not sure why you're automating the page before going to it. If the dupe doesn't answer your question, please share a runnable [mcve] and tag me and I'll reopen.
